# Perl script - add days to Date to get new date

Tags: perl, date

I am working on a perl script to add days to a date and display the newdate:

```
use Time::ParseDate;
use Time::CTime;

my $date = "02/01/2003";
my $numdays = 30;

my $time = parsedate($date);

# add $numdays worth of seconds
my $newtime = $time + ($numdays * 24 * 60 * 60);

my $newdate = strftime("%m/%d/%Y",localtime($newtime));

print "$newdate\n";

    The output will be:

    03/03/2003
```

Now how do I set the input for the date field to be yyyymmdd Ex: my $date = "20030102"

Also the output will need to be : 20030303

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean yyyyddmm as the format or 60 as the number of days to add?  Since adding 30 days to 20030102 (2nd January 2003) is not going to get you to 20030303 (3rd March 2003)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert $date from the input format to the old format:

```
$date =~ s%(....)(..)(..)%$3/$2/$1%;
```

If the output format should not be `%m/%d/%Y`, then do not set it to it. You obviously need `%Y%m%d`.

Answer (score 14):

You use [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/Time-Piece/Piece.pm) + [Time::Seconds](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-Piece/Seconds.pm) (in core since Perl 5.10),

```
use Time::Piece ();
use Time::Seconds;
my $date = '20030102';
my $numdays = 60; # 30 doesn't get us to march

my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime( $date, '%Y%m%d');
$dt += ONE_DAY * $numdays;
print $dt->strftime('%Y%m%d');
```

Comment: Is this accurate though? According to the documentation `ONE_DAY` is a constant, so it won't take into account things like daylight savings time or leap seconds.

Comment: That module doesn't work on systems / perl installs with year 2038 problems.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `DateTime` + `DateTime::Format::Strptime`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%m/%d/%Y'
);

# convert date to 
my $date = '02/01/2003';
my $dt   = $strp->parse_datetime($date);
printf "%s -> %s\n", $date, $dt->add(days => 30)->strftime("%d/%m/%Y");
```

**OUTPUT**

```
02/01/2003 -> 03/03/2003
```

Comment: Note: `DateTime.pm` is not included by default with many Linux distros.  See the answer below with `Time::*` packages which are included with core.